# When does a circuit, containing only independent voltage and current sources, violate Kirchoff's law?

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws

How do I know if the circuit below violates Kirchoff's law or not?

[image]

Comment: Welcome! What makes you believe it does? Is this homework?

Comment: Homework questions need to show some effort in solving the problem. Can you think of a really simple circuit that exclusively uses voltage sources that might violate the laws? Ditto a circuit that exclusively uses current sources?

Comment: Well, I think the sources should have values to tell... otherwise set all of them to zero and say no violation.

Comment: Kirchhoff's Voltage Law, and Kirchhoff's Current Law are _laws_. Therefore, you know in advance that they are not violated.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Would you accept "contradict" instead? :)

Comment: No! How could a circuit contradict a circuit law?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy It is not a circuit. It is a circuit model. If you have a schematic with two parallel voltage sources with different values and told that they are ideal and the resistance of the lines is zero - what would you call it?

Comment: Such a circuit model would be unrealizable. So that is what you mean. OK.

Comment: Bijoy, I see that you are not responding to anyone, yet. I read that as a poor sign. In any case, you can see a problem with (b) [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heCUb.png). Treat the voltage sources as arbitrary and see if there are node conflicts. Remove current sources on the left to see if there are any node conflicts, also. Etc.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because homework needs an attempt at a solution

Answer (score 3):

This is the kind of exercise designed to make you think about what Kirchhoff's Laws means.

If you think that these laws are just equations where you plug-in values, then yes, you can create a circuit where the laws are **violated**.

Here is one very simple. Pick an ideal DC voltage source and short-circuit it. No resistance, means that you end up with only one solution V=0. However, you can short-circuit a 12 V battery. What happens then?

The simplest answer is that your circuit is not not feasible. It does not exist. In the real world, we would have the resistance of the cable used to short-circuit the battery. As such, we would end up with Ohm's law: 12V = R.I. Based on the resistance, we can calculate the current.

Answer (score 2):

A voltage source is something whose potential difference is fixed, cannot change, but whose current can be *any* value.

Therefore, any closed path around a circuit which contains only voltage sources is problematic, with individual sources vying to impose different potentials upon the same node. I won't say that such an arrangement *necessarily* "violates KVL", because it's possible that all the source are 0V, or they all do actually add up to zero around the loop. All these are bad:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYEd07.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you find any such loop in your circuit, consisting exclusively of voltage sources, it's a potential violation (pun absolutely intended), not of any law, but rather of feasibility.

---

A current source can have *any* potential difference, but the current through it is fixed. Since the potential difference is flexible, "loops" of current sources are not necessarily problematic, and we focus on nodes where current branches, which concerns KCL.

Any junction in the circuit, where all branches contain a current source, is problematic, including a two-path junction (sources in series). In such a node, it is possible that all source are 0A, or their values do indeed total zero, which would not violate KCL, but generally these are bad:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f475Yd.png)</sup>

If you can find any node in the circuit whose branches all contain a current source, you have found a "violation", even if the branch contains other components in series with the source.

---

I understand why others here dislike the question's claim of some "violation of Kirchhoff's laws", I do too. Can you violate a "law"? Can you have two rods of 10cm length, end to end in a straight line and have the total length be anything other than 20cm?

If you add up all the voltages in a closed loop, and arrive at anything other than 0V, this isn't so much a violation of KVL as it is a situation which cannot exist in reality.

However, I think we all understand what you mean when you, or the professor, or the book says "violation of KVL or KCL", in the context of a hypothetical. I'm OK with that, as long as we all agree it can't happen in reality. At least, not in *this* one, and if our models are correct.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

It's `b` because there is a loop of only voltage sources

[image]

In general solve the circuit determining an expression for the voltage at each node and the current through each edge, if the circuit cannot be solved it violates kirchoffs laws.

In the case of circuit B the current in the edges marked in red   cannot be determined.

the easiest solving method for this analysis is probably superposition.

Comment: There is no values given for the voltage sources. It is possible to realize a circuit with only voltage sources if the sum of the voltages around the circuit algebraically add to zero.

Comment: No it is not,   When you do that the current is undefined.

Comment: @JasenСлаваУкраїні wow, "current is undefined" may be the most apposite fact on this page.

Comment: I'm astounded that it never occurred to me that a closed loop of only voltage sources has no element that relates current to voltage. All these years, and I'm still as dumb as I was on day 1.

Comment: this result  out in step one if you use the method of superposition.  https://www.khanacademy.org/science/electrical-engineering/ee-circuit-analysis-topic/ee-dc-circuit-analysis/a/ee-superposition.  if you instead go to simultaneous equations you'll also divide by zero or have a singular matrix.

Comment: @JasenСлаваУкраїні I'm not sure if your comment was meant in response to mine. Consider a circuit consisting of two equal voltage sources in opposite directions. The algebraic sum of the voltages is 0. Using Ohm's Law directly to calculate current gives a division by zero problem. However, taking limits as the wire and voltage source resistances  go to zero will result in a current of 0. The circuit model is as "realizable" as any other circuit model containing ideal voltage sources.

Comment: 0?  you're just making that up,  there is no re reason for it to be zero.  taking the limit as the voltages go from unequal to equal the current is infinite.

Comment: @JasenСлаваУкраїні If you have a circuit consisting of a resistance and two equal voltage sources in opposite directions in a loop, the current will be zero. Now make the resistance smaller, and the current will still be zero. The limit of the current as the resistance goes to zero will therefore be zero.

Comment: yes we have two limit expressions that give give different results,  This is why 0/0 is undefined. mathologer video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oc0M1o8tuPo

Comment: @JasenСлаваУкраїні When we analyse real circuits, we create an ideal model which ignores some aspects of the real circuit. It is manifestly possible to create a real circuit consisting of two (non-ideal) voltage sources in series but in opposite directions. In the real circuit the current will never be infinite, because real circuits do not have infinite current. Idealizing the circuit, by ignoring the resistance (taking a limit) gives an ideal model, which _by definition_ is realizable, because it is the idealization of a real circuit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144501/discussion-between-jasen---and-math-keeps-me-busy).